# Customize Contact to Case association in Email-to-Case functionality

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

In Email-to-Case functionality Contacts are automatically associated with Cases if matched email address is found in a Contact record.

I want this functionality to be customized, so that if Contact's Account Name and the Case priority set in the Email-to-Case configuration both matched, then only the Contact is associated with Case else it should not.

Comment: you'll need a trigger on Case to do this (essentially undo what SFDC does automatically)