# Email-To-Case Person Account Association

Tags: person-accounts, email2case

Using "Person Accounts", I'm discovering that cases created via `Email-To-Case` are not being auto-associated with the `PersonAccount` that shares the `PersonEmail` field. This [Knowledge Base](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212908&type=1) article mentions this exact flow - but only talks about Contact's?

Is it possible to *declaratively* associate cases created via `Email-To-Case` with a `Person Account` on the `PersonEmail` field? Or another email field for that matter (comment [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113178/customize-contact-to-case-association-in-email-to-case-functionality)  does not make it appear so)?

The goal is to get `Case Auto Response` rules working, but again, I am seeing this [is not possible](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124376/send-case-auto-response-email-to-associated-person-account) (obviously unless the Case is associated to a `Contact` or `Account` record), which happens OOTB if `Contact.Email` matches (and I'm not sure what field on `Account`??)

I can most likely replace the `Case Auto Response` with a `Workflow Rule`,

Comment: Unless absolutely necessary, or if it already exists in an org with existing customizations, try to avoid using Person Accounts.  I've been in dozens of orgs and have never seen a good implementation of PAs, nor have I seen justification to use it :-/

Comment: The last line of the KB you link states: `If the sender 'from' email address is related to unique Person Account record of the same email address, the association to the Case will occur.` Are you certain that you have been testing with a From address that matches exactly one Contact, either a PA or associated with a Business Account? An org I worked in used email-to-case extensively with PAs and this standard functionality worked as advertised. I don't fully agree with Brian's statement re: PAs. They absolutely have their place.

Comment: @BrianMiller - yes PA is a requirement outside of the scope of my interaction. @Thomas Taylor, I will recheck, but I am confident that I set the `PersonEmail` (`Email` is not a field on Account, even with Person Account active) field to match my test `From:` address.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor I've look and actually realized that my org (sandbox) is appending a string to the end of the email `.test` which would explain the issue I'm seeing need to see if this is default or workflow rule, or something else